# gmplot Google Maps html output not showing markers/heatmap

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, google-maps-markers

I am running gmplot in Pycharm (2018.1 Community) with Python Interpreter 3.5.4 (via Anaconda 1.5).

gmplot definitely creates the map.html, and the lat/longs are listed in the html.

However it does not appear to be plotting the lat/long on the image.

What am I missing?

Python Code:

```
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(lats[0],longs[0],15) #working
gmap.heatmap(lats, longs) #not working
gmap.draw('map.html')
```

HTML Output:

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps - pygmaps </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.218483, 29.042473);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: centerlatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var heatmap_points = [
new google.maps.LatLng(40.218483, 29.042473),
new google.maps.LatLng(40.218500, 29.042485),
###....(for the sake of brevity - removed)....
new google.maps.LatLng(40.220540, 29.043019),
new google.maps.LatLng(40.220569, 29.043032),
new google.maps.LatLng(nan, nan),
];

var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatmap_points);
var heatmap;
heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({

data: pointArray
});
heatmap.setMap(map);
heatmap.set('threshold', 10);
heatmap.set('radius', 10);
heatmap.set('opacity', 0.600000);
heatmap.set('dissipating', true);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Image opened by browsing to the HTML file on my local machine: (no markers!)
[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAsog.png)

And when I try to open the html file direct from PyCharm, I get Javascript errors that look like this:
[Firefox Javascript console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM9Vu.png)

This happens regardless of whether I use gmplot.scatter or gmplot.heatmap.
Do I need to put an API key somewhere?
Any ideas?

Comment: Worked it out!
Had to remove the NA and NaN entries first.